# XAML does not load UserControl from ViewModel object

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-3.5

I have a XAML code that should load my `UserControl` inside the `TabControl`.

If I put this XAML code:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="WorkspacesTemplate">
  <TabControl 
  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Gui}"
  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ClosableTabItemTemplate}"
  Margin="4"
  />
</DataTemplate>
```

I have absolutly nothing appear in the windows (Gui property is inside the ViewModel class and return a UserControl).

But if I put his XAML code instead of the previous one:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="WorkspacesTemplate">
  <TabControl 
  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding}"
  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ClosableTabItemTemplate}"
  Margin="4"
  />
</DataTemplate>
```

I have the ViewModel Object loading:

[image]
<sub>(source: [clip2net.com](http://clip2net.com/clip/m12122/1248018108-clip-3kb.png))</sub>

Here is a piece of code of the `TextBoxInputViewModel` that has the property Gui that should be binded to be able to get the Visual (usercontrol):

```
    private UserControl gui;

    public UserControl Gui
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.gui == null)
            {
                this.gui = new SimpleTextBoxInputControl();//Xaml User Control
                this.gui.DataContext = this;//Bind the Visual and ViewModel
            }
            return this.gui;
        }
    }
```

Any idea how that I can get the `UserControl` instead of this object reference text?

Comment: do you try to look in output window in case of ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Gui}"? output window shows binding errors, the message should help

Comment: Thank to notice me about the Output Windows. I see "System.Windows.Data Error: 32 : ObjectDataProvider needs either an ObjectType or ObjectInstance." But can't see if it's related to this binding or not.

Comment: I do not think it's related to that binding cause if I put the binding to itself it still have that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `ItemSource` is a collection, where as you're binding it to a property that is just one value. The error in the Output window that you're seeing is likely related to this.

Instead of returning a `UserControl` directly from your View Model, it would be better to return another View Model that represents the contents of the tab, and use templates to display that content. If you need it to be more dynamic than choosing the template based on the `Type` of the View Model, look into setting [TabControl.ContentTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol.contenttemplateselector.aspx). This needs to be set to a class that derives from [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx). You can use this class to decide which template to load based on the object bound to that tab.

Comment: Alright, tonight when back from work I will investigate from your point of view. I will let you know if it works or not.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is so obvious when you know. In fact, you light me up with the collection. I was so wrong, but instead of using DataTemplateSelector, I simply used ContentTemplate inside the TabControl and in the template I binded to the Path=Gui and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you should create a template for your viewmodel in your app.xaml file like this

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type simpleModel:TextBoxInputViewModel}">
        <myView:TextBoxInputControl />
    </DataTemplate>
```

where simpleModel is the namespace of TextBoxInputViewModel, and TextBoxInputControl is the user control you want to show and myView is the namespace of that user control.

Comment: Alright but the TextBoxInputViewModel might be an other control, it's dynamic this is why I cannot write it directly into the Xaml.